Extend algebraic morphism to a compactification with normal crossing boundary
Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are smooth algebraic variety over a char $0$ field $k$, and $f:X\to Y$ a morphism. I want to ask whether there exists compactifications $\bar X$ and $\bar Y$ such that $\bar X\setminus X $ and $\bar Y\setminus Y$ are normal crossing divisors, and $f$ extends to $\bar X\to \bar Y$? I'm not familiar with Hironaka's resolution of singularity, and any idea and references are welcome.

To be fair, most working algebraic geometers' knowledge of resolution of singularities consists of knowing the statements (and the proof in dimension $2$). You can deduce a positive answer to your question easily from Hironaka (plus Nagata compactification). Choose compactifications $\bar X$ and $\bar Y$ of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Blowing up in $\bar Y \setminus Y$, you can make $\bar Y$ smooth with normal crossings boundary. Replace $\bar X$ by the closure of the graph of $f \colon X \to \bar Y$ in $\bar X \times \bar Y$ to assume $f$ extends, and then apply resolution to $\bar X$.
